# Number of visitors on a specific page

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'd like to see the number of visitors on a specific page (for which I have URL).
I don't find in Analytics where to enter a URL in order to look for statistics for this specific page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps it would be on-topic at [Webmaster.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Go to Behavior > Site Content > All Pages and put your URI into the search box.[image]

Comment: Ok great ! Now I can see all the visits to a specific URL, perfect ! How can I find where did the visitors (of this specific page) come from ?

Comment: So once you see your link in the report, click it and select the 'Navigation Summary' tab toward the top of the page. This will give you both the previous page path and the next page path.

Comment: Thanks, but this shows only the previous pages *on my website*. I would like to know all external websites that link to this specific page URL of my website.

Comment: Ah, then you'll want to select your page from the report and apply a secondary dimension, such as Source.

Comment: The question is about visits, not page views.

Comment: Is it possible to have this report using embed api?

Comment: i don't see Site Content after clicking on Behavior. so how to view number of visitor on specific page?

Comment: @MarkThien - I had the same problem. "Behavior" appears twice in the same column. Scroll down further. It'll be there on the left sidebar. :)

Comment: We dont have "behavior" tab, only "Acquisition", "Engagement" and "Monetization". Im guessing the solution only works on older versions of GA?

Answer (score 44):

If you want to know the number of ***visitors*** (as is titled in the question) and not the number of ***pageviews***, then you'll need to create a custom report.

### Terminology

---

Google Analytics has changed the terminology they use within the reports. Now, visits is named "[sessions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en)" and unique visitors is named "[users](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en)."

**User** - A unique person who has visited your website. Users may visit your website multiple times, and they will only be counted once.

**Session** - The number of different times that a visitor came to your site.

**Pageviews** - The total number of pages that a user has accessed.

### Creating a Custom Report

---

1. To create a custom report, click on the "Customization" item in the left navigation menu, and then click on "Custom Reports".

[image: customization item expanded in navigation menu]

2. The "Create Custom Report" page will open.
3. Enter a name for your report.
4. In the "Metric Groups" section, enter either "Users" or "Sessions" depending on what information you want to collect (see *Terminology*, above).
5. In the "Dimension Drilldowns" section, enter "Page".
6. Under "Filters" enter the individual page (exact) or group of pages (using regex) that you would like to see the data for.
   [image]
7. Save the report and run it.

Comment: thanks, this is the most updated acceptable answer that worked

Comment: This is the more appropriate answer and should be used generally speaking as accounts move to using User ID and looking at conversion based on a User level instead of a session level

Comment: This solved the question on “number of visitors”.
The “Behavior” reports stated in the other answers show the sessions, not number of users. Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

As Blexy already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502866/1476885), go to "Behavior > Site Content > All Pages".

Just pay attention that "Behavior" appears two times in the left sidebar and we need to click on the second option:

[image: sidebar]

Comment: That is so terrible...What were they thinking?

Comment: It's confusing. I remember Ganalytics from 2009-2013, it was so simple and useful... 
They are continually changing options and their places. Without any common sense. One day one option is under one segment, next day it's under another.